# Including files and handling errors

Tags: php, error-handling

By old habit I've always used require over include. Basicly the two functions are exactly the same - besides require throws an error if the file does not exist and thus stops the script - where include will just throw a warning and continue on with the script as if nothing happened.

Normally when I dynamically include files I use something along the lines of if file_exists then require it. Looking like this:

```
<?php if (file_exists($file)) { require $file; } else { /*error handling*/ } ?>
```

As far as I know, and please correct me if I'm wrong, this is widely accepted as best practice and the most efficient way to handle it.

But I thought of another approach, which seems to be slightly faster and smarter in my opinion:

```
<?php if (!include $file) { /* error handling */ } ?>
```

I have not tested it yet, but it seems logical to me that it should be faster than the file_exists/require combo, as that requires 2 harddrive interactions where the include approach only requires one.

From my tests it works as expected. It inherits the scope that you would expect and variables set in it is accessible.

Is there any reason not to do this?

edit: typo

edit 2: one argument against this could be the E_Warning thrown when it tried to include a file which does not exist. That could be avoided by passing @ at include... Like this:

```
<?php if(!@include $file) { /* error */ } ?>
```

Comment: keep in mind the return value of the include statement is not necessarily a 1 or 0. You can use the return statement in the included file to return, say, an array. Aside from that, you're method is more solid than file_exists()... doing a file existence check(or any other check) doesn't mean the include will actually happen.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a "best practice".

You'll be including a file in one of three cases:

- if you need functionality from it - in other words, if your code would not function in the absence of that file
- if your code could use some functionality from that file to provide extra features, but works without it
- if your code could be *enhanced* by the inclusion of that file, but functions no differently without it (an example would be including a native SSL library versus using a pure-PHP one as a fallback; another example would be an "I need one of these libraries" situation, with all but the last falling into this grouping and the last one you try counting as "I need this" and going with the first bullet)

The only time you should use the if-include pattern you show here is in the second or third case, where having the file is nice but not necessary. In the first case, you should absolutely *not* do this - you should be using `require`. In the second case, you should strongly consider using `include` without the `if` statement. In the third case, you *might* use a conditional `include`, but see below.

The general "best practice" for managing includes in a PHP project where you can expect an `include` statement to **ever** fail without tanking the program is to define `__autoload` and have that handle your error correction, file-existence-checking, and so on.

To address your supposition that "it would be faster" to attempt the include and then detect failure: micro-optimization, especially that not backed by an empirical data, is the root of all evil. It doesn't matter whether it *might* be faster. First, determine whether you have a problem at all. **If yes**, then determine whether your `include` statements are significant enough in runtime that they're worth the programmer-hours you'd spend making them marginally better. If yes, then test whether your alternate implementation works properly. If yes, then benchmark both versions and see if the alternate is faster. Only then should you consider deploying it.

Comment: I agree with you - but I have one additional use case which you did not mention. I am using the dynamic including of files as a simple request handler in a simple web-app, and in that case I think the approach I found really useful. The errorhandling consists mostly of showing a 404-page.

Comment: @gustav You should be using a redirect for that, otherwise you'll be breaking all HTTP status codes and caching. Also, including a file is a form of evaluation, so doing it in response to a user request is very, very dangerous - what if they ask you to evaluate your `.htpasswd` file? The syntax error PHP spits out could contain password data.

Comment: I am validating the input before I try to load the file. If its anything else than letters and digits, I send them to the 404 before even trying. My error handling is registering the event in a database and sending the 404 header. I'm not literally showing them the 404-page :-)